# How to flatten objects in JavaScript (with or without lodash)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an object like

```
farmer:{
  name: "First Name",
  bank: {
    id: 7
  }
  certifications: [
   {
    certificateNumber: {
     id : 7
    },
    certificateNumber: {
     id : 8
    }  
   }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using lodash's set and unset method but that results in undefined values a lot often.I want to remove the id key from the above object completely

This is the result i want

```
farmer:{
  name: "First Name",
  bank: 7
  certifications: [
   {
    certificateNumber: 7,
    certificateNumber: 8 
   }
  ]
}
```

Comment: one object cannot have duplicate keys (so your input data type and expected result is invalid)

Comment: @NickParsons its not actually invalid. Its just that the later keys will overwrite the former. `{ a: 1, a: 2, a: 3 }` produces `{ a: 3 }`.

Comment: Why is certifications an array with a single object?

Comment: @max ah, you're right, I guess I should've said it "doesn't make much sense" instead of "invalid" :)

Comment: @J. Stoll this is how i get it from the database via a query and when i make a mutation i need to remove the object and send the id directly

Comment: That will never work as you will just get `certifications: [ { certificateNumber: { id : 8 } }]`. This is pretty much a textbook [X&Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem),  you should be asking how to actually query the db to get data that makes sense.

Comment: What database are you using and what is the query you are using to pull this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#transform) to iterate the structure recursively, and if an object has an `id` property, and its size (number of properties) is 1, replace the object with the `id` value.

Note: the `certifications` array is malformed and was changed to the following form `[{certificateNumber:{id:7}},{certificateNumber:{id:8}}]`.

```js
const fn = obj => _.transform(obj, (accumulator, value, key) => {
  let val = value

  if(_.has(value, 'id') && _.size(value) === 1) val = _.get(value, 'id')
  else if(_.isObject(value)) val = fn(value)

  accumulator[key] = val
})

const farmer = {"name":"First Name","bank":{"id":7},"certifications":[{"certificateNumber":{"id":7}},{"certificateNumber":{"id":8}}]}

const result = fn(farmer)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```